# Font not rendering on Mac/iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts, safari

I have an issue with a font not being rendered <strike>correctly</strike> at all on iOS and MAC OSX.  It renders correctly everywhere else I've tried, including a brand-new virtual Windows 7 machine.

It's really starting to grind my gears.

Here's my CSS for defining the font.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Knockout';
    src: local('☺'), 
         url('Fonts/knockout.otf') format('otf'), 
         url('Fonts/knockout.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Fonts/knockout.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/Fonts/knockout.svg#Knockout') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

For the legacy SVG file, here's the header:

```
<defs>
<font id="Knockout" horiz-adv-x="269" >
  <font-face 
    font-family="Knockout"
    font-weight="500"
    font-stretch="normal"
    units-per-em="1000"
```

And here's the LESS/CSS styling for the actual class where the font needs to be applied:

```
 .header
       {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            font-family: 'Knockout';
            color: @ColorTealD;
            font-size: 10vw;
            pointer-events: none;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
       }
```

As far as StackOverflow links I've visited:

[css @font-face doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695818/css-font-face-doesnt-work)

[Webfont not showing in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555484/webfont-not-showing-in-ios)

[@font-face not working in mobile Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856308/font-face-not-working-in-mobile-webkit)

I also visited a link that suggested using the smileyface trick, and another one that suggested prefacing the SVG URL with a '/'.  I also wiped the Safari cache on my iPhone. *I need to emphasize that this font appears in other browsers, including completely wiped virtual machines.*  Switching fonts isn't an option at this point, because $500 has been forked over for licensing.

Anyone have any ideas on what else I could do, to fix this?  I'm pretty sure the next steps involve throwing a virgin into a volcano or bloodletting a goat.

Comment: what exactly is not rendering correctly? I know that here is an issue with some browsers and font-weights using numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367589/font-weight-is-not-working-properly

Comment: There's no text.  Nothing is rendered to the screen, just a blank spot where content should be.

Comment: try clearing your cache.

Comment: Already tried that to no avail

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the browser and not the font or your code. Every browser renders the font differently. I also had this problem in chrome.

Did you try another font? If another font works, than it's the browsers fault.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the "Knockout 32" font original files. I opened it in FontForge and recreated it.